# How can I use proxy to HTTP traffic in android app (Android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm creating an android app with "Android Studio" and want to use Firebase service for login and sign up options in app. But Unfortunately firebase services are suspended in my country and it give 403 error.
I want a way to use proxy for firebase in my app that users doesn't need to enable VPN for registering in my app.
Is there any way to doing this?

Comment: Try Charles on your machine and go with emulator install the Charles certificate in your emulator...

Comment: @gobu-csg I want a way to include a proxy in my exported app and let all users use that to reach firebase services.

Comment: You're using sdk's right

Comment: I'm not sure May be you can try this one QUESTION ID: 22805368

Comment: @gobu-csg yes I'm using sdk. Thanks i will check it 